# Numba: indexing a vector is giving an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, numba

I started using python and numba recently. My problem is: I have a matrix (n rows and m columns).In a for loop I have to change the values ​​of specific columns.

Without numba, the code is running fine. But when I use njit(), it just crashes.

Note: In my real project, each row don't have the same values.

This is an example of what I need.

```
import numpy as np


def func_test(matrix_size, columns_idx, replace_values):
    matrix = np.zeros((matrix_size, matrix_size), dtype='int32')

    for i in range(0, matrix_size):
        matrix[i, columns_idx] = replace_values
    return matrix


columns_idx = [0,2,4]
replace_values = [1, 3, 5]

new_matrix = func_test(5, columns_idx, replace_values)
print(new_matrix)

[[1 0 3 0 5]
 [1 0 3 0 5]
 [1 0 3 0 5]
 [1 0 3 0 5]
 [1 0 3 0 5]]
```

Now, I will apply Numba.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit()
def func_test(matrix_size, columns_idx, replace_values):
    matrix = np.zeros((matrix_size, matrix_size), dtype='int32')

    for i in range(0, matrix_size):
        matrix[i, columns_idx] = replace_values
    return matrix


columns_idx = [0,2,4]
replace_values = [1, 3, 5]

new_matrix = func_test(5, columns_idx, replace_values)
print(new_matrix)
```

And this error appears:

> No implementation of function Function(<built-in function setitem>) found for signature:
>
> \>>> setitem(array(int32, 2d, C), Tuple(int64, reflected list(int64)<iv=None>), reflected list(int64)<iv=None>)
>
> There are 16 candidate implementations:
>
> - Of which 14 did not match due to:
>   Overload of function 'setitem': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
>   With argument(s): '(array(int32, 2d, C), Tuple(int64, reflected list(int64)<iv=None>), reflected list(int64)<iv=None>)':
>   No match.
> - Of which 2 did not match due to:
>   Overload in function 'SetItemBuffer.generic': File: numba/core/typing/arraydecl.py: Line 176.
>   With argument(s): '(array(int32, 2d, C), Tuple(int64, reflected list(int64)<iv=None>), reflected list(int64)<iv=None>)':
>   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
>   NumbaTypeError: unsupported array index type reflected list(int64)<iv=None> in Tuple(int64, reflected list(int64)<iv=None>)
>   raised from /Users/goncaloguedes/.conda/envs/Python_Fold_UnFold/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/typing/arraydecl.py:72
>
> During: typing of setitem at /Users/goncaloguedes/Desktop/Fold_Unfold/Python_Fold_UnFold/Testes.py (10)
>
> File "Testes.py", line 10:
> def func_test(matrix_size, columns_idx, replace_values):
> <source elided>
> for i in range(0, matrix_size):
> matrix[i, columns_idx] = replace_values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numba does not supports well **reflected list** (CPython lists with objects of possibly different types). You need either to use **typed lists** or **Numpy arrays**. The reason is that Numba need to work on well-defined typed variables and not on dynamically-typed objects so to be efficient (and actually be able to compile the code in a native binary). In your case, this is better to use Numpy arrays.

Additionally, it appear Numba is not able to compile a line like `matrix[i, columns_idx] = replace_values`. Not all Numpy features are supported by Numba yet. Thus, you need to use a basic loop instead.

Here is an example of corrected code:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit()
def func_test(matrix_size, columns_idx, replace_values):
    matrix = np.zeros((matrix_size, matrix_size), dtype=np.int32)

    for i in range(0, matrix_size):
        for j in range(0, columns_idx.size):
            matrix[i, columns_idx[j]] = replace_values[j]
    return matrix


columns_idx = np.array([0, 2, 4], np.int64)
replace_values = np.array([1, 3, 5], np.int32)

new_matrix = func_test(5, columns_idx, replace_values)
print(new_matrix)
```

Comment: I have one question. Why the variable "columns_idx" you use int64 and in "replace_values" int32 ?

Comment: This is not very important. I choose int64 because `i` was of type int64 (on 64-bit systems). If the array is big, it is better to use int32 (for both space and time efficiency). If it is small, it is sometime a bit faster to use int64 on some system. Note that having `replace_values` of the same type than `matrix` is important for speed however (since conversions introduce some overhead).